# Primefaces Datatable filterOptions from ArrayList

Tags: jsf, collections, primefaces, datatable, filtering

I want to load Primefaces 4 dataTable filterOptions read from database columns.
I used the Set interface to store distinct values for the options and then, put this distinct values in an ArrayList as above.

It is not clear for me Why am I getting **java.lang.ArrayStoreException**, since they are all integer values.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

The excerpt managed bean code:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> filteredPrefDeps;

public ArrayList<Integer> getFilteredPrefDeps() {
    return loadPrefDeps();
}

public void setFilteredPrefDeps(ArrayList<Integer> filteredPrefDeps) {
    this.filteredPrefDeps = filteredPrefDeps;
}

private ArrayList<Integer> loadPrefDeps() {
        Set<Integer> setList = new HashSet<>();        
        for (Upb id : getItems()) {
            setList.add(Integer.valueOf(id.getPrefDep()));
        }
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(setList);  
        return list;
    }
```

The jsf excerpt:

```
<p:column filterBy="#{item.prefDep}" filterOptions="#{upbController.filteredPrefDeps}" filterMatchMode="exact" >
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the documentation of this exception [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html)!

It will be thrown if you use the wrong type. It should be SelectItem.

```
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

List<SelectItem> filterLockedOptions = new ArrayList<SelectItem>(Arrays.asList(new SelectItem("value1","label1"),new SelectItem("value2","value2")));
```